# React, What happens if multiple effects setState a single value?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is it safe to do something like the following?

```
const [foo, setFoo] = useState(undefined)

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(someFunc()).then(response => {
    let { someFoo } = response
    setFoo(someFoo)
  })
}, []) // or  }, [bar])

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(anotherFunc()).then(response => {
    let { anotherFoo } = response
    setFoo(anotherFoo)
  })
}, [bar])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effects are executed in the given order and only the "foo" from the last effect setter will be visible in the UI. For instance, the following component will output bar - 1:

```
const Component = ({ bar }) => {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState(undefined);
  console.log("render", bar, foo);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("effect 1");
    let someFoo = bar + 1;
    setFoo(someFoo);
  }, [bar]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("effect 2");
    let anotherFoo = bar - 1;
    setFoo(anotherFoo);
  }, [bar]);

  return (
    <div>
      {bar} sets {foo}
    </div>
  );
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-leaf-g55n9?file=/src/App.js:76-482

**EDIT:** If you use [] as the dependency array, it will only execute once. If there's an **async** function inside the effect like **fetch**, the last executed setFoo will prevail. The following example will display random results in each click:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (disabled) {
      const random = 500 * Math.random();
      const handle = setTimeout(() => {
        setFoo(1);
      }, random);

      return () => clearTimeout(handle);
    }
  }, [disabled]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (disabled) {
      const random = 500 * Math.random();
      const handle = setTimeout(() => {
        setFoo(2);
      }, random);

      return () => clearTimeout(handle);
    }
  }, [disabled]);
```

Example 2:
https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-architecture-0ybcz?file=/src/App.js

Comment: what happens if `setFoo` is called asynchronously (I've changed the op..) sorry about that